# with bootstrap inline form, I want form elements to maintain style on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using bootstrap.  I have an inline form that has two rows of images.  On mobile devices, each image has its own row.  I want it to keep the two rows regardless of the size.

Here it is on desktop the way it is supposed to be:

[image: Desktop version]

And here it is on mobile:

[image]
Here is the media query i am using now that does not seem to be working:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { 
    .selfie_mobile_element{
        float: left;
    }
}
```

and here is the html and the rest of the added styles:

```css
.image_form_holder {
  padding: 25px 25px;
}
.image_input {
  display: none;
}
.color-form-groups {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft image_form_holder" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
    <img alt="Pick color" src="/assets/pick_color.svg" />

    <form class="form-inline" id="picture_form" method="post">
      <div id="color_list">
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups selfie_mobile_element">
          <div id="yellow">
            <label for="picture_shape_yellow_mask">
              <img alt="Yellowshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s2.postimg.org/54hv2icgp/yellowshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_yellow_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="yellow_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups selfie_mobile_element">
          <div id="pink">
            <label for="picture_shape_pink_mask">
              <img alt="Pinkshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s15.postimg.org/9bvctbmob/pinkshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_pink_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="pink_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups selfie_mobile_element">
          <div id="red">
            <label for="picture_shape_red_mask">
              <img alt="Redshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s14.postimg.org/rdoetat1d/redshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_red_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="red_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups ">
          <div id="blue">
            <label for="picture_shape_blue_mask">
              <img alt="Blueshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s8.postimg.org/8eye37oid/blueshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_blue_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="blue_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups">
          <div id="green">
            <label for="picture_shape_green_mask">
              <img alt="Greenshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s17.postimg.org/7b70mi40v/greenshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_green_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="green_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups">
          <div id="purple">
            <label for="picture_shape_purple_mask">
              <img alt="Purpleshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s1.postimg.org/lbwejz8vj/purpleshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_purple_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="purple_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups">
          <div id="cyan">
            <label for="picture_shape_cyan_mask">
              <img alt="Cyanshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s17.postimg.org/90bigtucf/cyanshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_cyan_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="cyan_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group color-form-groups">
          <div id="orange">
            <label for="picture_shape_orange_mask">
              <img alt="Orangeshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s2.postimg.org/48c6vko0p/orangeshape.png" />
            </label>
            <input class="image_input" id="picture_shape_orange_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="orange_mask" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>

        <label for="file_pic" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-file center-block">Upload a Selfie</label>
        <input id="file_pic" name="picture[pic]" type="file" />

      </div>
      <input class="img-responsive center-block" name="commit" src="/assets/submit_button.png" type="image" value="Comment" />


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I keep the two rows on mobile devices?

Comment: You can nest Bootstrap's grid, why not simply add two `.row`'s with both four `.col-xs-3` columns?

Comment: I tried that.  For some reason, it did not work.  It just stayed the same.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the padding of 25px on each side is breaking the rows. On a mobile real estate of only 320px, your padding is occupying 200px of that. I would remove the padding on the mobile media query.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the `.form-group` and `.form-inline` classes from your code example as there aren't any regular form elements. Inside the `form` I've added two `.row`'s with each four `.col-xs-3` columns. Instead of using the class `.image_input` to hide the radio buttons I've opted to add the Bootstrap class `.hidden` which achieves the same.

I've kept the `.col-md-6` class surrounding the entire form although I'm not sure if you want the form to take up the left part of the screen on the desktop `md` size. I've added a `.container` as every Bootstrap grid should have either a container like `.container` or `.container-fluid` around it (as this is the class on which the media queries operate).

If you don't depend on css classes like `.image_label` and `.image_input` for your JavaScript I think you can clean it up a little bit more.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInLeft image_form_holder" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
      <img alt="Pick color" src="/assets/pick_color.svg" />

      <form id="picture_form" method="post">
        <div id="color_list">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="yellow">
                <label for="picture_shape_yellow_mask">
                  <img alt="Yellowshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s2.postimg.org/54hv2icgp/yellowshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_yellow_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="yellow_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="pink">
                <label for="picture_shape_pink_mask">
                  <img alt="Pinkshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s15.postimg.org/9bvctbmob/pinkshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_pink_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="pink_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="red">
                <label for="picture_shape_red_mask">
                  <img alt="Redshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s14.postimg.org/rdoetat1d/redshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_red_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="red_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="blue">
                <label for="picture_shape_blue_mask">
                  <img alt="Blueshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s8.postimg.org/8eye37oid/blueshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_blue_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="blue_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="green">
                <label for="picture_shape_green_mask">
                  <img alt="Greenshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s17.postimg.org/7b70mi40v/greenshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_green_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="green_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="purple">
                <label for="picture_shape_purple_mask">
                  <img alt="Purpleshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s1.postimg.org/lbwejz8vj/purpleshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_purple_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="purple_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="cyan">
                <label for="picture_shape_cyan_mask">
                  <img alt="Cyanshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s17.postimg.org/90bigtucf/cyanshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_cyan_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="cyan_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div id="orange">
                <label for="picture_shape_orange_mask">
                  <img alt="Orangeshape" class="img-responsive image_label" src="http://s2.postimg.org/48c6vko0p/orangeshape.png" />
                </label>
                <input class="image_input hidden" id="picture_shape_orange_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="orange_mask" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <label for="file_pic" class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-file center-block">Upload a Selfie</label>
        <input id="file_pic" name="picture[pic]" type="file" />

        <input class="img-responsive center-block" name="commit" src="/assets/submit_button.png" type="image" value="Comment" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** I think your media query didn't work as it uses the LESS variable `@screen-xs-max`, are you sure you're converting LESS to CSS?